# How to check if an object is a string?

Tags: php

so, something which say `true` to

```
$a = 'text';
$a = '342';
$a = 1423;
```

values, and `false` to arrays, objects... anything else. Because `ctype_alnum()` doesnt say true to all of them. Neither `is_string()`. Isnt there a built-in function for that?

EDIT:
I know there is a `(string)` to cast the value, but it then fails if it gets an array. I want to get false, not an error

Comment: The third example is *not* a string

Comment: sadly, I want to regard it as string

Comment: You can't wish it into being. Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps `is_scalar()`?

Comment: You obviously don't want to check whether it's a string, because in that case, `is_string()` would be enough. What exacly do you want to check?

Comment: `ctype_alnum()` would return true for all 3 of your examples. Where did you see it fail? See http://3v4l.org/I0j9G

Comment: ...Or do you mean that you would accept all other string characters as well (which ctype_alnum() would reject) as in `ctype_alnum('123,456.222$$$$###')` which would be false?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, I examine a POST request, if I got a string. (I know its very hard, but in POST there is a change to get array, object...)

Comment: @JohnSmith You can't get an object in a POST request.

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't think there's any way to get an object from POST, you'll get strings or arrays only.  `is_scalar()` should be what you need.

Comment: I know its theoritically impossible, but what if somebody successfully generates POST request containing an array from a browser?

Comment: You have to be careful when providing numbers to `ctype_alnum()`.
Behaviour: http://ideone.com/VEldbN
Please see the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

Comment: @JohnSmith Well, as Michael said, POST variables are strings or arrays only. Check for array using `is_array()`. If it fails, then it's string.

Comment: an object in $_POST would have to be json-encoded or php serialize()'d. and at that point it's just a string like any other.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, see the code in the previous-previous post. This is why ctype_alnum() is bad. http://ideone.com/HcUfvY is_scalar() is the winner

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, [as documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) in the "Note" regarding signed ints `-128..255`.  An unexpected behavior indeed.

Comment: @Karolis You suggested `is_scalar()` here - you should post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`is_scalar` — Finds whether a variable is a scalar. Scalar variables are those containing an integer, float, string or boolean. Types array, object and resource are not scalar.

*Source:* http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php